# I have a RegEXP dictionary in array [{"$regex":/name/i}]

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I have a RegEXP dictionary in array `[{"$regex":/name/i}]` when I do `JSON.stringify` or `JSON.parse` this array the regular expression is removed in the array. Please let me know how it will remain same after converting
I am doing as follow

```
var tmpArr= [{"$regex":/name/i}] 
var newArr = JSON.stringify(tmpArr)
```

it removes the regular expression

```
"[{"$regex":{}}]"
```

Comment: is this javascript? if so, add that `tag` you'll get better help.  And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I think you need to escape the slashes in the string by prepending a backslash like this: `var tmpArr= [{\"$regex\":\/name\/i}]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RegExp` string constructor instead of a literal regex. Like this:

```
var tmpArr= [{"$regex":{pattern: "name", flags: "i"}}] 
var newArr = JSON.stringify(tmpArr)
```

Then when you need to use the regex, you use the string constructor:

```
var regex = new RegExp(tmpArr["$regex"].pattern, tmpArray["$regex"].flags);
```